# SharePoint 2013 site collection search settings versus farm search settings

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search, enterprise-search, managed-property

I have been struggling with a problem for a few months now. No matter what I tried, I could not get the information form the Title field to show rather than the Title in the document. I was doing this for a specific site collection.  As other posts advised , I did move "MetadataExtractor" down in the list of mapped properties. This had intermittent success. Just when I would think it was fixed, I would find another document that still wasn't correct ( either in a different library or different document type ) . I finally removed all crawled properties and mapped Title to another crawled text property that I have added to the site collection. Title was *still* showing from document properties. So then the farm admin mapped Title for the farm to another user text field. So now Title is showing as the text field mapped at Central Admin and not the one locally.

I thought that the mappings for managed property on the site collection overrode the mappings on the farm. Is this just happening because Title is a special field ?

Thanks

Comment: Did you map the property in the Site Collection where you are executing the query?

Comment: Yes, I did . I mapped it at the site collection.

Answer (score 0):

Can you change mappings for managed property on the site collection?
I cannot change mappings for managed property on the site collection：
[image]

To get the information form the Title field to show rather than the Title in the document, you can move the MetadataExtractorTitle down in the list of mapped properties,move the ows_Title crawled property up in the list of mapped properties.

Then perform an index reset and do a full crawl.

Reference:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/spses/2013/10/30/show-more-relevant-titles-in-search-results-in-sharepoint-2013-plus-some-other-improvements/

Comment: Did all that. Did not work setting it at the site collection level. Title from the farm settings ( central admin search schema) is overriding anything I do at the site collection level.

Comment: Hello, I did move MetadatExtractor down. The link you provided says that ows_Title refers to the page name. That link says to use TermTitle. However, after a lengthy  call to MS , where one person told me to use TermTitle, and another told me to use Basic:displaytitle, it turns out Office:2 gives the title for most of the document types ( even zip ).  I pointed out this page to them and they said they would have it updated.